# How to make subscription with arguments correctly in GraphQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

In **AWS AppSync** I tried to test my **GraphQL** schema. I'm a little confused and need help. My subscription called `watchMessages` doesn't work when there is an argument. If I remove the argument from schema and test it, it works. But I only need to receive messages from a specific room. What am I missing?

```
input CreateMessageInput {
    roomId: String!
    messageText: String
    messageAuthor: String
}

type CreateMessageOutput {
    messageId: String!
    messageCreatedDateTime: String!
    messageText: String!
    messageAuthor: String
}

type Mutation {
    createMessage(input: CreateMessageInput): CreateMessageOutput
}

type Subscription {
    watchMessages(roomId: String!): CreateMessageOutput
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createMessage"])
}
```

I make such **subscription query**:

```
subscription MySubscription {
  watchMessages(roomId: "5d354323") {
    messageId
    messageCreatedDateTime
    messageText
    messageAuthor
  }
}
```

I make such **mutation query**:

```
mutation MyMutation {
createMessage(input: {roomId: "5d354323", messageAuthor: "Bob", messageText: "Hello!"}) {
    messageId
    messageCreatedDateTime
    messageText
    messageAuthor
  }
}
```

Comment: how invoked? how args passed ? ... passing variables is described in many graphql docs

Comment: I opened two different tabs in the AWS console. On first tab, I first signed up for a subscription called `watchMessages`. Next, in the second tab, I call the mutation called `createMessage`. Mutation works out without problems. In the first tab with a subscription, I don't get any results. If you remove the argument from the subscription (graphql schema) and try to test it as well, the subscription works. I assume that I made out the arguments in the subscription scheme incorrectly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: params hardcoded - should be passed as variables but it doesn't matter in this case ... subscription implementation details/code?

Comment: I do not test programmatically, so there is no code as such.

Comment: what? no subscription resolver [code]?

Comment: I have a program code for mutation written in Python, but for testing subscriptions, I think the AppSync console will be enough. What do you recommend I do in the end?

Comment: where is the [subscription] room matching logic?

Comment: Apparently, it's not there. What should it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. All subscription parameters must exist as a field in the returning type.  This means that the type of parameter must also match the type of the field in the returning object. I added `roomId` field to the `CreateMessageOutput` type.

```
type CreateMessageOutput {
    roomId: String!
    messageId: String!
    messageCreatedDateTime: String!
    messageText: String!
    messageAuthor: String
}
```