# AWS amplify and angular integration getting started - Connect API and database to the app

Tags: angular, graphql, aws-amplify, subscription

From the [getting started](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/angular/) tutorial by amazon, I've been unable to get the subscription to work. It seems that the api has changed and now there is a filter parameter.The method that I'm having trouble with is that api.OnCreteRestaurantListener().

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.api.ListRestaurants().then((event) => {
    this.restaurants = event.items as Restaurant[];
  });

  // TODO: subscription not working - figure it out
  this.subscription =
    this.api.OnCreateRestaurantListener().subscribe((event: any) => {
      const newRestaurant = event.value.data.onCreateRestaurant;
      this.restaurants = [newRestaurant, ...this.restaurants];
    }) as Subscription;
}
```

If I dont pass any parameter, I get a `"Connection failed: { "errors":[{ "message":"Validation error of type UndefinedVariable: variable not found" }]}"`. And if I pass a blank object {}, the error stops. Either way, when I create a new restaurant, my app doesn't updade and the new restaurant only appears if I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Keep in mind, this is my first day with GraphQL.*

After 6 straight hours of running into the same thing... I sorta have a solution to this.

One thing to note with subscriptions is [all subscription parameters must exist as a field in the returning type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308456/how-to-make-subscription-with-arguments-correctly-in-graphql). Otherwise, this issue occurs.

That being said, I don't know why it doesn't work with [input types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types) that resolve to the same base type.

For example, name ultimately resolves to a string:

`{name: ModelSubscriptionStringInput}` -> `{ name: { eq: String }}`

---

My solution was to remove the `$filter` argument from the schema in AppSync (you can get there by running `amplify console api` then choosing GraphQL), then use `amplify pull` to bring those changes down locally, then use `amplify codegen` to update the generated code in my app (note that any changes you made to the generated code will be overridden).

Obviously this isn't a solution if you want to have filtered subscriptions with complex input types... sorry about that.

Overall it seems like that angular guide could use some work. [(It's had a history of being like this)](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5284)

Oh also, the `Subscription` class can be from `rxjs`. I spent so long trying to figure out how to use the `zen-observable-ts` one... only to find out they both work.

Hopefully this helps, good luck with your app!

---

Here are some resources I picked up on my adventure to solve this problem.

[AWS AppSync "Real-time data" (aka subscriptions) documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-data.html#using-subscription-arguments)

[AWS AppSync Enhanced subscription filtering documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-enhanced-filtering.html#aws-appsync-real-time-enhanced-filtering-defining-from-client) (this is where I think the real solution is... I just need to wrap my head around it.)

[GraphQL Documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/)

[The Differences between GraphQL and REST APIs](https://www.guru99.com/graphql-vs-rest-apis.html)